# Fix @Body Parameter encryption in Retrofit in sign build?

Tags: java, android, module, retrofit

I'm sending params in `@body` using retrofit from another module but its automatically encrypt in a , b , c ...

I added `'proguard-rules.pro'` in module and also tried `@SerializedName("name")` but both doesn't work.

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keep class com.argaam.** { *; }
```

Because of this encryption server does't receive params and return `5oo` server code with error message did not revised parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You should also keep your model classes

```
# -keep class com.your.package.model.** { *; }
```